# Signing Twitter trends API v1.1 request in PHP fails

Tags: php, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

Since Twitter API version 1.1 **every** request has to be authenticated and signed via OAuth 1.0a. In my PHP project I want to make use of the Twitter trends API, especially I want to use the GET trends/place call. So it's read-only.
Now, to authorize a request there's an excellent Twitter API documentation [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request). We learn that we have to send an additional header in the HTTP request, called "Authorization" that contains a string starting with "OAuth " and including seven parameters:

1. oauth_consumer_key
2. oauth_nonce
3. oauth_signature
4. oauth_signature_method
5. oauth_timestamp
6. oauth_token
7. oauth_version

Of those seven parameters the above mentioned third one, oauth_signature, is kind of special because to build its value you have to include all the other parameters plus more and then sign it. The process, again, is explained very well [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature).

I implemented all these steps after registering my app and getting consumer key & secret and access token & secret. Here's my PHP code (I crossed-out the secrets, of course):

```
    $HTTPmethod = 'GET';
$twitterApiBaseUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json';
$twitterApiParams  = 'id=' . $WOEID;
$twitterApiCallUrl = $twitterApiBaseUrl . '?' . $twitterApiParams;

$OAuthConsumerKey = 'eV78fJOOiObfeytAwvWCg';
$OAuthAccessToken = '1116971396-6uc4xOLziLAdiqOfrtKfuRraa2GdCzas9aQX8ZB';
$OAConsumerSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$OATokenSecret    = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// building the necessary (as of Twitter API v1.1) authorization header
// according to https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request
$DST = 'OAuth ';

// 1.: Consumer key
$oaConsumerKeyKey = rawurlencode("oauth_consumer_key");
$oaConsumerKeyVal = rawurlencode($OAuthConsumerKey);
$DST .= $oaConsumerKeyKey . '="' . $oaConsumerKeyVal . '", ';

// 2.: Nonce
$oaNonceKey = rawurlencode("oauth_nonce");
$oaNonceVal = rawurlencode(base64_encode(time()));
$DST .= $oaNonceKey . '="' . $oaNonceVal . '", ';

// 3.: Signature method
$oaSignatureMethodKey = rawurlencode("oauth_signature_method");
$oaSignatureMethodVal = rawurlencode('HMAC-SHA1');
$DST .= $oaSignatureMethodKey . '="' . $oaSignatureMethodVal . '", ';

// 4.: Timestamp
$oaTimestampKey = rawurlencode("oauth_timestamp");
$oaTimestampVal = rawurlencode(time());
$DST .= $oaTimestampKey . '="' . $oaTimestampVal . '", ';

// 5.: Token
$oaTokenKey = rawurlencode("oauth_token");
$oaTokenVal = rawurlencode($OAuthAccessToken);
$DST .= $oaTokenKey . '="' . $oaTokenVal . '", ';

// 6.: Version
$oaVersionKey = rawurlencode("oauth_version");
$oaVersionVal = rawurlencode('1.0');
$DST .= $oaVersionKey . '="' . $oaVersionVal . '", ';

// 7.: Signature
// according to https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature
$preSignatureBaseString = $twitterApiParams;
$preSignatureBaseString .= '&';
$preSignatureBaseString .= $oaConsumerKeyKey . '=' . $oaConsumerKeyVal;
$preSignatureBaseString .= '&';
$preSignatureBaseString .= $oaNonceKey . '=' . $oaNonceVal;
$preSignatureBaseString .= '&';
$preSignatureBaseString .= $oaSignatureMethodKey . '=' . $oaSignatureMethodVal;
$preSignatureBaseString .= '&';
    $preSignatureBaseString .= $oaTimestampKey . '=' . $oaTimestampVal;     
$preSignatureBaseString .= '&';
$preSignatureBaseString .= $oaTokenKey . '=' . $oaTokenVal;
$preSignatureBaseString .= '&';
$preSignatureBaseString .= $oaVersionKey . '=' .$oaVersionVal;

print "<b>preSignatureBaseString:</b> $preSignatureBaseString<p/>\n";

$signatureBaseString = $HTTPmethod;
$signatureBaseString .= '&';
$signatureBaseString .= rawurlencode($twitterApiBaseUrl);
$signatureBaseString .= '&';
$signatureBaseString .= rawurlencode($preSignatureBaseString);

print "<b>signatureBaseString:</b> $signatureBaseString<p/>\n";

$signingKey = rawurlencode($OAConsumerSecret) . '&' . rawurlencode($OATokenSecret);

$oaSignatureKey = rawurlencode("oauth_signature");
$oaSignatureVal = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $signatureBaseString, $signingKey));

print "<b>oaSignatureVal:</b> $oaSignatureVal<p/>\n";

$DST .= $oaSignatureKey . '="' . rawurlencode($oaSignatureVal) . '"';

print "<b>DST:</b> $DST<p/>\n";

$header = "User-Agent: MyCoolTwitterTrendsApp\r\n" .
          "Authorization: " . $DST . "\r\n";              
$opts = array(
        'http' => array(
           'method'    => $HTTPmethod,
           'header'    => $header
        ));
print "<b>header:</b> $header<p/>\n";

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

$twitterApiResponse = file_get_contents($twitterApiCallUrl, false, $context);

$decodedResponse = json_decode($twitterApiResponse);

echo $decodedResponse;
```

Problem is, the actual call to the API fails every time with an "HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized" error. Can anyone tell my why and what I'm doing wrong here?
Thank you so much!

Comment: oauth doesn't use `rawurlencode()`, it uses `str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($v))`.

Comment: But in all honesty, I would throw this away and use a library instead.

Comment: Jack, I used rawurlencode() because that's what the official Twitter doc says for PHP developers ...

Comment: Using a library is a bit of an overkill because this is the one and only call my mini application will ever have to do. No need for a full blown library that's capable of doing all Twitter stuff one can imagine.

Comment: Plus, imagine I want to write a Twitter library -- I really want to learn and understand why this is not working. ;-)

Comment: Obviously I didn't mean a library that handles all Twitter stuff, I meant one for OAuth stuff.

Comment: Here's the link to the Twitter API doc where they say that in PHP we have to use rawurlencode() when they say "percent encode": https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/percent-encoding-parameters

Comment: Well, then the doc is wrong, because `rawurlencode()` is NOT fully RFC3986, as explained in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the same problem i have but try to check the timestamp mine was off exactly by 1 hour, go figure what that is!! daylite saving time

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
        $oauth_hash = '';
        $oauth_hash .= 'oauth_consumer_key=YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY&';
        $oauth_hash .= 'oauth_nonce=' . time() . '&';
        $oauth_hash .= 'oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&';
        $oauth_hash .= 'oauth_timestamp=' . time() . '&';
        $oauth_hash .= 'oauth_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN&';
        $oauth_hash .= 'oauth_version=1.0';
        $base = '';
        $base .= 'GET';
        $base .= '&';
        $base .= rawurlencode('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json');
        $base .= '&';
        $base .= rawurlencode('id=23424848&'.$oauth_hash);
        $key = '';
        $key .= rawurlencode('YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET');
        $key .= '&';
        $key .= rawurlencode('YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET');

        $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base, $key, true));
        $signature = rawurlencode($signature);
        $oauth_header = '';
        $oauth_header .= 'oauth_consumer_key="YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY", ';
        $oauth_header .= 'oauth_nonce="' . time() . '", ';
        $oauth_header .= 'oauth_signature="' . $signature . '", ';
        $oauth_header .= 'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", ';
        $oauth_header .= 'oauth_timestamp="' . time() . '", ';
        $oauth_header .= 'oauth_token="YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN", ';
        $oauth_header .= 'oauth_version="1.0", ';
        $curl_header = array("Authorization: Oauth {$oauth_header}", 'Expect:');
        $curl_request = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_header);
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=23424848');
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        var_dump(curl_exec($curl_request));
        curl_close($curl_request);
```

I have Modified the code to get user timeline from [this blog](http://blog.jacobemerick.com/web-development/working-with-twitters-api-via-php-oauth/)